# Applymap capwords to multiple columns only if values are UPPERCASE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with multiple blank values and different data types per column. For example I have the following dataframe I want to select the columns "Name", "Country" and "Job" and apply capwords to all this column only if value is ALL CAPSLOCK (can convert all into str before and that is not a problem). So this dataframe:

```
ID  Name    Country Job
1   PAULO   BRAZil  JOHN'S DRIVER
2   Joao    $   -
3   Maria   np.nan  DriveR
3   MARIA   Portugal    DRIVER
4   PEdro   ARGENTINA   DRIVER
```

Would return this output:

```
ID  Name    Country Job
1   Paulo   BRAZil  John's Driver
2   Joao    $   -
3   Maria   np.nan  DriveR
3   Maria   Portugal    Driver
4   PEdro   Argentina   Driver
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `applymap` for each value

```
import string

cols = ['Name', 'Country', 'Job']

df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda val: string.capwords(val) if val.isupper() else val)
```

```
print(df)

   ID   Name    Country            Job
0   1  Paulo     BRAZil  John's Driver
1   2   Joao          $              -
2   3  Maria     np.nan         DriveR
3   3  Maria   Portugal         Driver
4   4  PEdro  Argentina         Driver
5   5  PEdro  Argentina         Driver
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for that! Is there a way I could use the same solution but instead of title case to use "capwords"? I believe it would be better to handle names with apostrophe.

Comment: @PauloCortez Show an example?

Comment: Please refer to this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199966/python-title-with-apostrophes

I added an example to the data. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. sorry, I just checked and the function transforms the blank values into "nan" into string format. Can it returns the np.nan as described.

Comment: @PauloCortez Don't understand, give an example.

Comment: In the same example I gave, 3rd row for me where country was "np.nan" it returns "nan" in string format

Comment: @PauloCortez Don't understand what `np.nan` is, is this a literal string or a type? In any case, you can special handle it in the lambda function. The lambda function also can be extended to a user defined function.

Comment: applymap has an argument "na_action = 'ignore" to handle NaN cases as you can see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html so I believe that would work